# Converting between Alloy Primitive and Storage Types

Tags: arbitrum, rust, stylus

How can we convert, for instance, the Address type from Alloy Primitives into the StorageAddress type from the Stylus crate?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `from()` or `into()`. The SDK [uses](https://github.com/OffchainLabs/stylus-sdk-rs/blob/f0709fc517388f706a455b3289f4a6d122147f5f/stylus-sdk/src/storage/mod.rs#L505) Alloy's primitives behind the scenes.

That being said, it's rare that you have to do this conversion yourself, because the Stylus team has made sure that [API boundaries](https://github.com/OffchainLabs/stylus-sdk-rs/blob/f0709fc517388f706a455b3289f4a6d122147f5f/stylus-sdk/src/storage/mod.rs#L450) use Alloy primitives, that is, you declare your Solidity struct inside `sol_storage!` and forget that the backing types are `Storage*`.